# How do i add dynamic page titles in this structure?

Tags: php, dynamic

As you can see below I am checking the `$_GET['page']` to include the correct page into my `index.php`, I like this structure but how do I add dynamic data like the title to the header? the `init.php` which includes the `header.php` the file is included at the top before the correct page is included in the `index.php` so it's not possible for me to just use a variable?

Can someone please explain to me how others do this?

init.php

```
//HEADER OPTIONS
header('X-FRAME-OPTIONS: deny', true);
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
header("x-content-type: nosniff");
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );

session_start();

 if(!isset($_SESSION['CSRFToken'])){
     //SÆTTTER SESSION TOKEN HVIS DER IKKE ER EN
     $_SESSION['CSRFToken'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
 }

require_once "db.php";
require_once "functions.php";
require_once 'header.php';
```

index.php

```
include_once "includes/init.php";

// CHECKKER OM DER ER EN $_GET
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? "pages/" . $_GET['page'] . '.php' : 'pages/core.php';
// CHECKER OM FILEN EKSISTERE
file_exists($page) ? include_once($page) : include_once "pages/404.php";

include_once "includes/footer.php";
```

Comment: How are you extracting `$_GET['page']`? It seems like someone could potentially fetch pages that they shouldn't using this method? Are you using an `.htaccess` rewrite or something?

Comment: Also, where are your titles coming from for each page? Do you fetch them from a database or where do the titles actually come from?

Comment: What do you mean by this? i just check if the page is existing in theh 'pages' folder and if it exists it will get included :) ?

Comment: Right now i put in a static page title, i'd like this to change, thats why i am asking here how people do. becuase i dont see how i can do this

Comment: To point 1, It's just a question, not likely to happen, but if someone were to automate a bot to probe your site that would loop through a whole host of possibilities like  `?page=../../index` and your page then would try and find `pages/../../index.php` or whatever. Someone could possibly include a page you are not intending to include. Just keep that in mind that it's possible.

Comment: In terms of the second point, let's say there is a way to include a custom title on each page, where are you going to get the titles for each page? From a database or array or where?

Comment: If you want to do it this way (routing), you may want to have a method to make sure that the page is only including pages from a certain folder. For instance, you could use `basename()` to strip out everything except the last part of the string. That way a person couldn't fool your inclusion and add a page it's not supposed to.

Comment: I think i figured a way to solve my main problem, i will just rearrange everything a little and do a database call with all the information needed. About the security issues, can you specify your suggestion a bit more i dont get what you exactly want me to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162950/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-ii-iml0sto1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` to replace the current text in the title tag with whatever title you want.

So you can initially set your title text in the `header.php` or wherever it is with a placeholder like `<title>%TITLE%</title>`

Then after you include the correct the file you can set the title with the php code below which uses `ob_get_contents` to get whatever has been output to the browser at that point and use `str_replace` to replace it,

```
<?php

    $buffer=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","NEW TITLE",$buffer);
    echo $buffer;
?>
```

Let me know if it helps or if i can help you more.

Comment: Hi this worked great, sorry for the very late accepted answer.